# aspectj - stackoverflowerror when accessing thisJoinPoint.getTarget()

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I am trying to advise a large 3rd party application with the following pointcut/advice to intercept all field accesses:

```
before(Object target): get(* *) && target(target) && !within(aspect) {
     logger.debug("Pointcut: " + thisJoinPoint);
     logger.debug("Target: " + target);
}
```

For most field accesses this works fine, however for a particular access the second debug line causes a StackOverflowError and the method that contains the field appears to be repeatedly executed up to the line of the field access.
If I remove the second debug line the problem goes away - so it seems that using thisJoinPoint.getTarget() is causing the problem. The same issue occurs for getThis(), however not for thisJoinPoint.getSourceLocation() or thisJoinPoint.getSignature()

Comment: `+ target` is calling the toString() method on the target which may be doing a field get?

Comment: The object doesn't override its toString() method so this shouldn't access any fields

Comment: actually logging target.toString() causes the problem but logging target.hashcode() and target.getClass().getName() do not...this seems strange to me since the default toString() just uses these 2

Answer (score 2):

You need to exclude either the advice execution's or alternatively the `toString` method's control flow from your pointcut.

This sample code replicates your problem:

**Driver application:**

There are mostly auto-generated methods incl. `toString` and `hashCode`.

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
    private String name;

    public Application(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Application other = (Application) obj;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Application [name=" + name + "]";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Application("foo").equals(new Application("bar"));
    }
}
```

**Aspect with failing advice (StackOverflowError):**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

public aspect FieldAccessLoggingAspect {
    before(Object target): get(* *) && target(target) && !within(FieldAccessLoggingAspect) {
        System.out.println("Pointcut: " + thisJoinPoint);
        System.out.println("Target: " + target);
    }
}
```

**Aspect with fixed advice:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

public aspect FieldAccessLoggingAspect {
    before(Object target): get(* *) && target(target) && !cflow(adviceexecution()) {
        System.out.println("Pointcut: " + thisJoinPoint);
        System.out.println("Target: " + target);
    }
}
```

**Alternative for fixed advice (not so nice, but also working):**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

public aspect FieldAccessLoggingAspect {
    before(Object target): get(* *) && target(target) && !cflow(execution(public String Object+.toString())) {
        System.out.println("Pointcut: " + thisJoinPoint);
        System.out.println("Target: " + target);
    }
}
```

**Update:** Just in case `cflow()` does not do the trick in your situation because the problem happens deeper down the callstack, you can also use `cflowbelow()`. But only do that if necessary.